# regex sieve script not matching

Tags: dovecot, regex, sieve

I have a problem on a dovecot2 mail server with a sieve script I write.
The script should automatically move mail coming from a mailing list to a folder (by list name, not list id)

```
require ["fileinto", "mailbox", "variables", "regex"];
if exists "list-id" {
    if header :regex "list-id" "([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]+[a-zA-Z0-9.])" {
        fileinto :create "${1}";
        stop;
    }
}
```

For a mail with the header

`List-Id: RZ Monitoring <rz-monitoring.lists.example.com>`

This script should move all mail to a folder "RZ Monitoring". But for some reason all mail is piling up in the inbox instead.

The script is getting executed and I have no errors in my logs so I must have made a mistake in the script itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the following worked:

```
require ["fileinto", "mailbox", "variables", "regex"];
if exists "List-Id" {
    if header :regex "List-Id" "([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-_. ]+[a-zA-Z0-9.])" {
        fileinto :create "${1}";
        stop;
    }
}
```

Like Andrew Schulman pointed out, it seems that "exists" is case sensitive.
After fixing this, I ran into an error in the logs. In the regex

```
([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]+[a-zA-Z0-9.])
                      ^
```

this "-" is interpreted as a range from "9" to "_", ehich is not valid (Though as far as my understanding of regex is, it shouldn't. Possibly a quirk of dovecots regex implementation). So the "-" here has to be escaped

```
([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-_. ]+[a-zA-Z0-9.])
```

Comment: `[0-9-_. ]` does indeed mean "from 9 to _" in regex. The escape character can be omitted if the dash appears immediately following the opening square bracket, or immediately preceding the closing one (eg. `[-_0-9]` or `[0-9_-]`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Dovecot sieve docs](https://wiki1.dovecot.org/LDA/Sieve) aren't clear about this - I think you'd have to dig into the RFCs - but I think that the `exists` operator is case sensitive, although `:regex` isn't. So you should use `List-Id` instead of `list-id`:

```
if exists "List-Id" {
    if header :regex "List-Id" "([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]+[a-zA-Z0-9.])" {
        fileinto :create "${1}";
        stop;
    }
}
```